# How to remove main file and use main wrapper when I using AppDelegate and SwiftUI?

Tags: swift

I want to have full control on my macOS app in SwiftUI therefor I am using a main file beside my AppDelegate and then using my SwiftUI view as a contentView of window like this:

1: main.file

2:

```
    class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    private lazy var window: NSWindow = NSWindow()
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        // codes here for custom NSWindow ...
        
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: ContentView())
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
        
    }

}
```

So I was thinking how to make improvement by removing the main file and using someway like this:

```
@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    private lazy var window: NSWindow = NSWindow()
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        // codes here for custom NSWindow ...
        
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: ContentView())
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
        
    }

}
```

I did tried the code, the app get lunched but I cannot see any window, I am not sure is this way could be a thing and if it is how I can make this way works? By the way I am not using also I don't need to use ViewController. Just AppDelegate and SwiftUI View. If i cannot use the main wrapper "@main" for solving the issue, can I make my own custom main wrapper like this "@customMain" and somehow defining the main file there?